# plain http images with a https/ssl page

Tags: http, ssl, https

Is it still not kosher to have a https page with images that are not accessed via SSL? (ie imagine a web app which is SSL for all important content, but images and styles are coming via a plain http CDN).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Correct, it's still not kosher. It will cause warnings in many browsers about "mixing secure and insecure content."