# plain http image on https/ssl page = warning

Tags: image, http, ssl, https, warnings

I've found the page that [plain http images with a https/ssl page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2986487/plain-http-images-with-a-https-ssl-page) can't be displayed without warnings. Are there any way to display a picture from another http:// web-site on your https://web-site without warnings? (suppose you have a permission to display that picture on you web-site).

Chrome put a yellow triangle on SSL locker: "...However, this page includes other resources, that are not secure..."
IE displays a warning when a page loads: "Do you want to view only the webpage content that was  delivered securely?"

So, how to display a picture on https:// page if it is on another web-server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the information on [this article](http://encosia.com/cripple-the-google-cdns-caching-with-a-single-character/) on Encosia. Basically you have to use a // syntax for your urls in order to use the same protocol in all cases. For example, if you have a https request, the following

> //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js

will hit google's CDN using the https protocol. However, if you don't have control over the other server, i think you're out of luck. If you *do* have control over the other server i'd recommend using the method described in the article above by allowing your content server to serve both protocols.